# Portfolio optimization with Python/CVXPY: DCPError

Tags: programming, portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, optimization

I'm trying to implement a script for portfolio optimization on a sample universe of 3 future contracts.

I have the following inputs:

- current allocation --> number of contracts currently held for each of
  the 3 futures
- contracts_size --> the size (in USD) of each of the 3
  futures
- ptf_size --> the USD size of my portfolio
- trans_costs_per_contract --> the USD transaction costs per contract
  traded for each of the 3 futures
- exp_return --> expected return for    each of the 3 futures
- covar_matrix --> 3x3 covariance matrix
- ptf_target_vol --> the target standard deviation of the portfolio
- min_contracts / max_contracts --> the min/max number of contracts I want to held for each future

I need to find the number of futures contracts to held (contracts_number) that maximize the after costs sharpe ratio. Since we are dealing with futures, the number of contracts must be integer and can be either positive or negative.

I tried this script:

```
contracts_number = cp.Variable(3, integer=True)
dollar_exposure = cp.multiply(contracts_number, contracts_size)
percent_weights = dollar_exposure / ptf_size

delta_contracts = cp.abs (contracts_number - current_allocation)
perc_trans_costs = (delta_contracts @ trans_costs_per_contract) / ptf_size

ptf_exp_return = (percent_weights @ exp_return) - perc_trans_costs
ptf_risk = cp.quad_form(percent_weights , covar_matrix)
exp_sharpe = ptf_exp_return / ptf_risk

constraints = [min_contracts <= contracts_number, contracts_number <= max_contracts, ptf_risk<= (ptf_target_vol+0.002), ptf_risk>= (ptf_target_vol-0.002)]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(exp_sharpe), constraints)
prob.solve(solver="CPLEX", verbose=True, cplex_params={"timelimit": 180})
```

but I get the following error:

```
DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
((var64 @ [61628.06739  84486.713     6960.371795] / Promote(100, (3,))) @ [0.08751445 0.10975094 0.09182673] + -abs(var64 + -[0. 0. 0.]) @ [1.5 1.5 1.5] / 100) / QuadForm(var64 @ [61628.06739  84486.713     6960.371795] / Promote(100, (3,)), [[0.06792497 0.01680063 0.01909388]
 [0.01680063 0.10450343 0.02311845]
 [0.01909388 0.02311845 0.12322165]])
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: If you haven't done it already, then it is a good idea to read [the package documentation](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dcp/index.html#dcp-problems). It has a small section on DCP-problems. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the problem was in the two portfolio risk contstraints. I set Maximize(ptf_exp_return) as solver goal and, in this way, I could define just one risk constraint (ptf_risk<= ptf_target_vol+0.002). I need to check better, but now the script seems to work